# How can i apply this effect with Css and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, matrix, slide

i think I can apply this effect to the matrix on the site I gave here. I suspect i could not find the slide effect...

https://appico.com/

If you can help, please be very happy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the two libraries given below to achieve the required effect

1. [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)
2. [Velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/)

Hope this helps.
Thanks